# Python Check if String split succeeded

Tags: python, string

I am splitting a string `"name:john"` and want to check whether the split happened or not. What is the right way doing that check?

**A quick solution:** (but maybe overkill)

```
name = "name:john"
splitted = name.split(":")
if len(splitted) > 1:
    print "split"
```

Is there a more elaborate way of doing the check?

Comment: Your way looks fine to me :-)

Comment: The only case it wont split is when `:` is not in string..So you can check before splitting.Is str.find(":") something like that

Comment: @vks Probably should prefer `in` keyword there. No need for `find` when you don't need what it returns.

Comment: Similar to your approach, but I'd explicitly would check that the outcome of the split resulted in exactly two items, i.e., `if len(splitted) == 2:` ... since that's what you specified/are looking for.

Comment: How many items should each split produce? 2, 3, 4, 5 - will it always be the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also choose the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach: split, unpack and handle `ValueError`:

```
try:
    key, value = name.split(":")
except ValueError:
    print "Failure"
else:
    print "Success"
```

Comment: I would add an `else` block after the `except`, and move the `print "Success"` from the `try` block to the `else` block.

Answer (score 7):

Why not using `in` operator?

```
if ':' in name:
    print "split"
```

Or if you want `:` to be presented between the first and end characters you can simply do:

```
if ':' in name[1:-1]:
    print "split"
```